# Optimizing Polars Algorithm: Dynamic Rolling Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, python-polars

I need to compute stable prices for financial instruments based on trade timestamps and market data using polars in Python. However, I'm encountering some difficulties in implementing this functionality efficiently.

#### Problem Description:

I have two pandas dataframes:

market_data: Contains timestamps and corresponding prices of financial instruments.
trades: Contains timestamps of trades, along with the instrument and quantity traded.

#### Example Data:

- **Trades Dataframe:**

| timestamp | instrument | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01T09:02 | AAPL | 100 |
| 2024-01-01T09:07 | GOOG | 50 |

- **Market Data:**

| timestamp | mid_price |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01T09:00:01 | 100.1 |
| 2024-01-01T09:00:02 | 100.1 |
| 2024-01-01T09:00:03 | 100.13 |
| 2024-01-01T09:00:04 | 100.14 |
| ... | ... |
| 2024-01-01T23:59:58 | 101.3 |

For each trade in the trades DataFrame, I need to compute the stable price of the instrument starting from the trade timestamp. The end of the stable price period is determined by when the price variation of a rolling window of market data exceeds a specified threshold. Additionally, if the stable price window exceeds a maximum time limit, I need to skip the trade and move to the next one.

#### Current Approach:

I've implemented a function compute_stable_price() that iterates over the market data from the trade timestamp, checking the price variation of a rolling window until it exceeds a threshold or the window size exceeds a maximum limit. The trade is skipped if the window size exceeds the maximum limit. I then apply this function to each trade timestamp in the trades DataFrame.

```
# Function to compute stable price
def compute_stable_price(trade_timestamp, market_data, threshold=0.5, max_window=10):
    trade_price = market_data.filter(pl.col("timestamp") == trade_timestamp)["price"][0]
    start_index = market_data.filter(pl.col("timestamp") == trade_timestamp).head_index()[0]
    end_index = start_index
    window_size = 1
    while end_index < len(market_data) - 1:
        end_index += 1
        window = market_data.slice(start_index, end_index + 1)["price"]
        price_variation = window.pct_change().std()
        if price_variation > threshold or window_size > max_window:
            break
        window_size += 1
    if window_size <= max_window:
        stable_price = market_data["price"][end_index]
    else:
        stable_price = None
    return stable_price

# Compute stable prices for each trade
stable_prices = trades\
    .with_column(
        pl.col("timestamp"),
        compute_stable_price(pl.col("timestamp"), market_data)
    )
```

#### Request for Assistance:

While the current implementation seems to work, I'm worried about its performance, particularly when handling larger datasets, as it currently takes a significant amount of time to execute (approximately 2 hours).
I'm open to suggestions for optimizing the algorithm or exploring alternative approaches to achieve the same functionality more efficiently using Polars.

Comment: Some things in your code example are not valid: `.head_index()`, `.with_column()` - `trade_timestamp` is being set to `pl.col("timestamp")` which means the filters would return `True` for all rows. It makes things easier if you provide a runnable example.